# Programmatically listen to network call for specific url

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to be able to monitor when my app is making a network call to specific url

For example to capture calls to

> http://test12345.com

I need to do it using code not external tools

Comment: You can create your custom class and implement logging. And at certain point based on certain event, you can send these log to your dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate all URL calls via a single class, have that check the URL before calling and if it matches your criteria log this out.

Comment: I am not the one who is initiating the requests, i operate as some kind of external sdk